# Search arraylist of objects does not work

Tags: java, arraylist, iterator

I have been encountering a specific problem where only the first item in Arraylist is included when it comes to iterating each element in Arraylist (to search/to remove). That means that the second until n-1 iteams won't be found whenever I try to iterate.
Edited: currently improving my code.

You could try the following program. It is perfectly working **only** when adding the first record of the order: I can remove and search its values. However, when adding the second order: I can not remove and search its values, rather it is not found.

Source code

```
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;

public class TestOrders {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException, IOException, NoSuchElementException {

        File afile = new File("order.txt");
        FileOutputStream outFile = new FileOutputStream("order.txt");
        ObjectOutputStream outStream = new ObjectOutputStream(outFile);

        FileInputStream inFile = new FileInputStream("order.txt");
        ObjectInputStream inStream = new ObjectInputStream(inFile);

        //Create an arraylist of order
        ArrayList<Order> theorder = new ArrayList<>();

        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println("Welcome to Order");
        System.out.println("Please choose an option (1-5): ");
        int choice = 0;
        try {
            while (choice != 5) {   
                //A list of options 
                System.out.println("\n1. Add a new order: ");
                System.out.println("2. Search an order: ");
                System.out.println("3. Compute sum of all orders:");
                System.out.println("4. Remove an order: ");
                System.out.println("5. Exit: ");

                //prompt user
                System.out.print("Pick a number: ");
                if (scan.hasNextInt()) {
                    choice = scan.nextInt();
                }

                switch(choice) {

                    case 1:
                        addNewOrder(outStream, theorder);
                        break;
                    case 2:
                        searchOrder(outStream, inStream, theorder);
                        break;
                    case 3:
                        computeSum(afile, theorder);
                        break;
                    case 4:
                        removeOrder(outStream, inStream, theorder);
                        break;
                    case 5: 
                        System.exit(0);
                        break;
                    default:
                        System.out.println("Please enter from (1-5)");
                }
            }
        } catch (IOException | InputMismatchException ex) {
                System.out.println(ex);
        } finally {
                if (choice == 5) {
                    scan.close();
                    outStream.close();
                    inStream.close();
                }
        }
    }

    public static void addNewOrder(ObjectOutputStream outStream, ArrayList<Order> theorder) throws IOException {

            Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
            Order anorder = new Order();

            System.out.print("Enter the order ID: ");       
            anorder.setOrderID(input.nextInt());
            input.nextLine();

            System.out.print("Enter the customer name: ");      
            anorder.setCustomerName(input.nextLine());

            System.out.print("Enter the order (meal/drink): ");
            anorder.setOrderType(input.nextLine());

            System.out.print("Enter the order price: ");
            anorder.setPrice(input.nextDouble());

            if(theorder.size() <= 1000) {
                theorder.add(anorder);
                outStream.writeObject(anorder);
                System.out.println("Order information saved.\n");
            } else {
                System.out.println("There is not enough space.");
            }
    }

    public static void searchOrder(ObjectOutputStream outStream, ObjectInputStream inStream, ArrayList<Order> theorder) throws FileNotFoundException {


        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        Order o = new Order();

        System.out.println("Please enter a customer ID: ");
        int custID = input.nextInt();

        for (Order or : theorder) {
            if(or.getOrderID() == custID) {
                System.out.println(or.toString());
                break;
            } else {
                System.out.println("No matching record found");
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    public static void computeSum(File aFile, ArrayList<Order> theorder) throws FileNotFoundException, IOException {

            double sum = 0;

            for (Order o : theorder) {
                    sum += o.getPrice();        
            }

            sum = (double) Math.round(sum*100)/100;

            System.out.println("The total sum of price for " + theorder.size() + " orders is " + sum);
    }

    public static void removeOrder(ObjectOutputStream outStream, ObjectInputStream inStream, ArrayList<Order> theorder) {

            Iterator<Order> iterator = theorder.iterator(); 
            Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

            System.out.println("Enter the order ID to remove: ");
            int custID = input.nextInt();

            while (iterator.hasNext()) {
                Order anorder = iterator.next();
                if(anorder.getOrderID() == custID) {
                    theorder.remove(anorder);
                    System.out.println(anorder.toString());
                    break;          
                } else {
                    System.out.println("Not found\n");
                    break;
                }
            }

            for (Order o : theorder) {
                System.out.println(o.toString());
            }
    }
}
```

Order class

```
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;

public class Order implements Serializable {
    private int orderID;
    private String customerName;
    private String orderType;
    private double price;

    public Order() {
    }

    public Order(int orderID, String customerName, String orderType, double price) {
        this.orderID = orderID;
        this.customerName = customerName;
        this.orderType = orderType;
        this.price = price;
    }

    public int getOrderID() {
        return orderID;
    }

    public void setOrderID(int orderID) {
        this.orderID = orderID;
    }

    public String getCustomerName() {
        return this.customerName;
    }

    public void setCustomerName(String customerName) {
        this.customerName = customerName;
    }

    public String getOrderType() {
        return this.orderType;
    }

    public void setOrderType(String orderType) {
        this.orderType = orderType;
    }

    public double getPrice() {
        return price;
    }

    public void setPrice(double price) {
        this.price = price;
    }

    public String toString() {
        return this.orderID + " " + this.customerName + " " + this.orderType + " " + this.price + "\n";
    }
}
```

This part is where I am struggling. I had tried using iterator but it got the same result, second item cannot be iterated/found.

```
                for (Order o : theorder) {
                if(o.getOrderID() == orderIDSearch) {
                    theorder.remove(orderIDSearch);
                    System.out.println("Order has been successfully removed");              
                    continue;
                } else {
                        System.out.println("Not found ");
                        break;
                }
            }
```

What should I do to fix this problem? is there any way it can be solved?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
for ( Order o : theorder ) {
    if ( o.getOrderID() == orderIDSearch ) {
        theorder.remove(orderIDSearch);
        System.out.println("Order has been successfully removed");              
        continue;
    } else {
        System.out.println("Not found ");
        break;
    }
}
```

There are several problems here:

First, removal of an element of a collection whilst iterating across the collection requires a different technique than you are using.  Generally, modifying a collection in the midst of iteration will result in a `ConcurrentModificationException`.

Second, are multiple matches expected?  If there is at most one match, the `continue` should be a `break`.

Third, one would expect the code to continue to following elements when a current element is not a match.  That is, the `break` should be a `continue`, or better yet, should be removed entirely.

Fourth, its not clear that `theorder.remove(orderIDSearch)` will do anything, unless the collection type has a `remove` operation which takes a key value instead of an element value.  For basic collection types (`List`, `Set`), the call won't do anything.

Here are two rewrites:

If the iterator supports remove:

```
Iterator<Order> orders = theorder.iterator();
boolean found = false;
while ( !found && orders.hasNext() ) {
    if ( orders.next().getOrderID() == orderIDSearch ) {
        found = true;
    }
}
if ( found ) {
    orders.remove();
    System.out.println("Found and removed [ " + orderIDSearch + " ]");
} else {
    System.out.println("Not found [ " + orderIDSearch + " ]");
}
```

If the iterator does not support remove, then:

```
boolean found = false;
for ( Order o : theorder ) {
    if ( o.getOrderID() == orderIDSearch ) {
        found = true;
        break;            
    }
}
if ( found ) {
    theorder.remove(orderIDSearch);
    System.out.println("Found and removed [ " + orderIDSearch + " ]");
} else {
    System.out.println("Not found [ " + orderIDSearch + " ]");
}
```

Note that this relies on `remove` accepting a key as the parameter value.

Comment: Highly appreciated your answers, comments and informative approaches. Thank you for the help :)

Answer (score 0):

You are breaking the loop in for search in else condition.
Why would you do that.. Remove the else part